# Golang, ioutil.ReadFile при тестировании не находит документ

Tags: golang, io

Добрый день!

Есть сервер, который при запросе читает файл и выдает его в json клиенту.

В controller.go имею такую функцию -

```
func InitJsonFile() Data {
raw, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./components.json")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err.Error())
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Сервер работает, нареканий нет.Написал тест controllers/controller_test.go

```
 func TestController(t *testing.T) {
    data :=InitJsonFile()
   }
```

При запуске go test ./... получаю no such file in directory.
Как я понял, это из-за того, что тесты запускаются не из корня проекта, а из папки, где находится controller_test.go и соответственно по относительному пути этот файл не виден.
Подскажите как выйти из этой ситуации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте абсолютные пути. Для переносимости приложения можно использовать два подхода:

1. `pwd` - пример [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537257/golang-how-to-get-the-directory-of-the-currently-running-file)
2. Описывайте путь к документам в config-файле:

   ```
   ;путь к документам
   work_dir=/path/to/docs/
   ```

Пример работы с файлами конфигурации:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strings"
)
const (
    DEBUG    = 1
    CONFIG   = "./app.cfg"
)
type CfgVars struct {
  WorkDir string
}

var configfile string
var cfgvars CfgVars

func init() {
    var cfgRaw = make(map[string]string)
    flag.StringVar(&configfile, "config", CONFIG, "Read configuration from this file")
    flag.StringVar(&configfile, "c", CONFIG, "Read configuration from this file (short)")
    flag.Parse()

    rawBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(configfile)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }

    text := string(rawBytes)
    lines := strings.Split(text, "\n")
    for _, line := range lines {
            fields := strings.Split(line, "=")
            if len(fields) == 2 && strings.HasPrefix(fields[0], ";") == false {
                    cfgRaw[strings.TrimSpace(fields[0])] = strings.TrimSpace(fields[1])
            }
    }
    if len(cfgRaw) > 0 {
            if cfgRaw["work_dir"] != "" {
                    cfgvars.WorkDir = cfgRaw["work_dir"]
            } else {
                    cfgvars.WorkDir = "/tmp/"
            }
    }
  }

func main() {
  log.Println(cfgvars.WorkDir)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Абсолютные пути использовать можно, но есть решение лучше - **testdata** 
https://medium.com/@povilasve/go-advanced-tips-tricks-a872503ac859#bb3a

- директория testdata не включается в билд
- ее видит ioutil.ReadFile через относительный путь

  ```
  bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("testdata/match-profile.html")    
  document, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(strings.NewReader(string(bytes)))    
  if nil != err {    
  t.Error(err)    
  }
  ```